# Iterate over Nested Objects in Array and delete the Property names and Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have the array as below and what I want to do is to remove the Property names i.e keys and values from the below array based on the values in the other array.

Options would be to create a new array as below with only values from the Keep Array or to remove the values which are not listed in the "keep" array from the original array.

```
var Keep=["ItemID","ItemNumber","OptionNo","Quantity","Price","Description","StockStatus","Url"]; 
var originalarray=[
      {
        "ItemID": 1,
        "ItemNumber": "611741",
        "OptionNo": "22",
        "SizeDescription": "3-6 Mths",
        "Price": "14.00",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "StockStatus": "instock",
        "StockMessage": "In Stock",
        "WarrantyItem": null,
        "Description": "Coral/Blue Embellished Two In One Dress (3mths-7yrs)",
        "Url": "/g82272s2",
        "FulfilmentType": ""
      },
      {
        "ItemID": 2,
        "ItemNumber": "912767",
        "OptionNo": "13",
        "SizeDescription": "11 EU 29",
        "Price": "16.00",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "StockStatus": "instock",
        "StockMessage": "In Stock",
        "WarrantyItem": null,
        "Description": "Silver Buckle Corkbed Sandals (Younger)",
        "Url": "/g82272s2",
        "CustomItemFields": [],
        "FulfilmentType": ""
      }
    ]
```

I tried to get the new array created but the array is not nested so I have multiple entries in for the same key with different values as below:

```
["ItemID:1", 
"ItemNumber:611741", 
"OptionNo:22", 
"Price:14.00", 
"Quantity:1", 
"StockStatus:instock", 
"Description:Coral/Blue Embellished Two In One Dress (3mths-7yrs)", "Url:/g82272s2", 
"ItemCategory:Dresses", 
"ItemID:2",
 "ItemNumber:912767", 
"OptionNo:13", 
"Price:16.00",
 "Quantity:1", 
"StockStatus:instock", 
"Description:Silver Buckle Corkbed Sandals (Younger)", 
"Url:/g82272s2", 
"ItemCategory:Sandals"]

I want the result array to be like this 

[{"ItemID:1", 
"ItemNumber:611741", 
"OptionNo:22", 
"Price:14.00", 
"Quantity:1", 
"StockStatus:instock", 
"Description:Coral/Blue Embellished Two In One Dress (3mths-7yrs)", "Url:/g82272s2", 
"ItemCategory:Dresses"}, 
{"ItemID:2",
 "ItemNumber:912767", 
"OptionNo:13", 
"Price:16.00",
 "Quantity:1", 
"StockStatus:instock", 
"Description:Silver Buckle Corkbed Sandals (Younger)", 
"Url:/g82272s2", 
"ItemCategory:Sandals"}]
```

This is my Code:

```
var keep=["ItemID", "ItemNumber", "OptionNo", "Quantity", "Price", "Description", "ItemCategory", "StockStatus", "Url"],z={}; z=new Array(); y.forEach(function(arrays){
  // 4 arrays in a
  var x=Object.keys(arrays);
  var k=Object.values(arrays); 
  //console.log(x);
  //console.log(y);
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  //console.log(x[i]);
 keep.forEach(function(item,index,array){
      if(item==x[i]){
          //z.push(x[i]+":"+y[i]);
         z.push(x[i]+":"+k[i]);
          return z;
                    }
  })
 }
  })
```

Hope you can help.

Thank you.

Comment: Wait, do you want to remove all properties in the `remove` array? Or you want to keep them?

Comment: Sorry, my Mistake I changed the name of the array from "Remove" to "keep" while posting here to make more sense but did not change the reference to it in the code.I make the change now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update***:
For the sake of it, here's the [lodash](https://lodash.com) version, may be easier to read, too:

```js
const keep = (k, l) => _.map(l, o => _.pick(o, k))

const keepThese = ["ItemID", "ItemNumber", "OptionNo", "Quantity", "Price", "Description", "StockStatus", "Url"]
const orig = [{"ItemID": 1, "ItemNumber": "611741", "OptionNo": "22", "SizeDescription": "3-6 Mths", "Price": "14.00", "Quantity": 1, "StockStatus": "instock", "StockMessage": "In Stock", "WarrantyItem": null, "Description": "Coral/Blue Embellished Two In One Dress (3mths-7yrs)", "Url": "/g82272s2", "FulfilmentType": ""},
  {"ItemID": 2, "ItemNumber": "912767", "OptionNo": "13", "SizeDescription": "11 EU 29", "Price": "16.00", "Quantity": 1, "StockStatus": "instock", "StockMessage": "In Stock", "WarrantyItem": null, "Description": "Silver Buckle Corkbed Sandals (Younger)", "Url": "/g82272s2", "CustomItemFields": [], "FulfilmentType": ""}]
console.log(keep(keepThese, orig))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

*Docs:* [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map), [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick)

---

The following `keep` function will do this, although there might be a more elegant way using [lodash](https://lodash.com), for example.

```js
const keep = (k, l) => l.map(o => Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [n, v]) => 
  k.includes(n) ? (r[n] = v, r) : r, {}))

const keepThese = ["ItemID", "ItemNumber", "OptionNo", "Quantity", "Price", "Description", "StockStatus", "Url"]
const orig = [{"ItemID": 1, "ItemNumber": "611741", "OptionNo": "22", "SizeDescription": "3-6 Mths", "Price": "14.00", "Quantity": 1, "StockStatus": "instock", "StockMessage": "In Stock", "WarrantyItem": null, "Description": "Coral/Blue Embellished Two In One Dress (3mths-7yrs)", "Url": "/g82272s2", "FulfilmentType": ""},
  {"ItemID": 2, "ItemNumber": "912767", "OptionNo": "13", "SizeDescription": "11 EU 29", "Price": "16.00", "Quantity": 1, "StockStatus": "instock", "StockMessage": "In Stock", "WarrantyItem": null, "Description": "Silver Buckle Corkbed Sandals (Younger)", "Url": "/g82272s2", "CustomItemFields": [], "FulfilmentType": ""}]
console.log(keep(keepThese, orig))
```

*Explanation*: 
[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the input to 
[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) 
[`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)'d to an `Object`, starting from `{}`.
So `(r, [n, v]) => k.includes(n) ? (r[n] = v, r) : r` runs for each property in each object in the array. 
If the array of properties to keep [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the current property's name, add the corresponding property & value to `r`. Otherwise don't touch `r`. Repeat for next property, at the end add `r` to result array.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this. It works well. Can you please explain the code a little bit more so I can understand and learn.

Comment: Jesus H. Christ, apart from the fact that the code is unreadable for beginners in JavaScript, why is this downvoted? It works perfectly fine, and I see no reason why would anyone downvote it.

Comment: @user1222256 Added a bit of explanation, let me know if some part of the code needs more

Comment: @wentjun I don't know in this case but random downvoting seems to be the standard on SO nowadays

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you study the use of `map()` and `filter()` and even `find()`.

See the documentation for using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) or [Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

With them you can perform various validations and transformations on objects in your array.

And to exclude a key with the value of an object you will need:

```
delete myObject.regex;
// or,
delete myObject['regex'];
// or,
var prop = "regex";
delete myObject[prop];
```